# React native get realtime database data not working (firebase)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native and trying to build a simple app with firebase as backend.

I have made a sign-up, login, logout and setting a mobilenumber. I'm trying to read the mobilenumber data realtime. The function to get the data is as follow:

```
    _listenForMobileNumberChanges(userId, callback) {

    let userMobilePath = "/user/" + userId + "/details";

    firebase.database().ref(userMobilePath).on('value', (snapshot) => {

        var mobile = "";

        if (snapshot.val()) {
            mobile = snapshot.val().mobile
        }

        callback(mobile)
      });
    }
```

In the render function I placed a ListView and called the function:

```
<ListView
        dataSource={this.state.mobile}
        renderRow={() => {this._listenForMobileNumberChanges(this.state.userId}}
     />
```

I know i'm missing the callback parameter in the Listview call, but I don't know what to add to the parameter, could anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a Listview use TextInput instead and in the onChangeText attribute for the TextInput make a call to the metode like this:

```
    <TextInput
      style={{height: 40, borderColor: 'gray', borderWidth: 1}}
      onChangeText={(usermobileNumber) => this._listenForMobileNumberChanges()}
      value={this.state.usermobileNumber}
    />
```

Parse no parameters just modify the methode to this:

```
_listenForMobileNumberChanges() {
    alert('inside the listen function');

    if(firebase.auth().currentUser) {
      let userId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
      let userMobilePath = "/user/" + userId + "/details";

      firebase.database().ref(userMobilePath).on('value', (snapshot) => {

          var mobile = "";

          if (snapshot.val()) {
              mobile = snapshot.val().mobile
          }

          this.setState ({usermobileNumber: mobile});
      });
    } else {
      this.setState ({usermobileNumber: ''});
    }
  }
```